# Does ActiveAdmin have a standard set of CSS classes to modify links to buttons?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Basically, I need to modify a link to a button as it happens in Bootstrap by adding class 'btn btn-primary' but I don't want to add Bootstrap library. Probably ActiveAdmin already has something similar to this but I can not find it in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Take what you need from Bootstrap [button](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/_buttons.scss) and [variable](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/054f8781a86b16c3793eaf424093a5d4cfb37114/scss/_variables.scss) code (it is open source) and copy to your `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.scss` or another css file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `a(:class => 'button', href: ...) { "your button link" }`  if I'm reading

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/components/_buttons.scss

correctly. Greetings!